# Is optimizing small std::strings wiht c-style functions often pointless?

Tags: c++, string, char, malloc

Let's say we've got the following piece of code and we've decided to optimise it a bit:

```
/// BM_NormalString
bool value = false;       
std::string str;
str = "orthogonal";
if (str == "orthogonal") {
    value = true;
}
```

So far we've come up with two pretty simple and straightforward strategies:

```
/// BM_charString
bool value = false;
char *str = new char[11];
std::strcpy(str, "orthogonal");
if (std::strcmp(str, "orthogonal") == 0) {
    value = true;
}
delete[] str;
```

```
/// BM_charStringMalloc
bool value = false;
char *str = (char *) std::malloc(11);
std::strcpy(str, "orthogonal");
if (std::strcmp(str, "orthogonal") == 0) {
    value = true;
}
free(str);
```

If we try and [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/wguqyb1w5kDwjhngA-txaI6NLVU) our three approaches we, quite surprisingly, won't see much of a difference.
Although bench-marking it locally gives me even more surprisingly disconcerting results:

```
|      Benchmark       |     Time         |    CPU    |    Iterations |
|----------------------|------------------|-----------|---------------|
|    BM_charString     |     52.1 ns      |  51.6 ns  |    11200000   |
| BM_charStringMalloc  |     47.4 ns      |  47.5 ns  |    15448276   | 
|  **BM_NormalString** |     17.1 ns      |  16.9 ns  |    40727273   |
```

Would you say then, that for such rather small strings there's almost no point in going 'bare metal' style (by using C-style string functions)?

Comment: Not sure why you would expect c-style strings to be faster in the first place. Especially for such simple examples.

Comment: *and we've decided to optimise it a bit:* -- You should construct the string with the data instead of constructing an empty string.  [See this](https://quick-bench.com/q/hgJwWKJrlUhMTL-PU2nbddcftso).  Also, as the answer by @eerorika pointed out, the implementers of the `std::string` class for the compiler are not run-of-the-mill C++ coders.  Whatever advantage they can find in optimizing string operations, they will find it.  If they truly thought that `malloc`-ing the memory was faster, they would know about it and use it.

Comment: Thank you, @PaulMcKenzie. That reduces the time from 17ns to 8ns in my local bech-marking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For small strings, there's no point using dynamic storage. The allocation itself is slower than the comparison. Standard library implementers know this and have optimised `std::basic_string` to not use dynamic storage with small strings.

Using C-strings is not an "optimisation".